# How to calculate Optical Flow magnitude in OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matrix, opticalflow

I'm trying to see how big different two given video frames are. My goal is to calculate a single value showing how fast objects inside those frames are moving.

I can calculate Optical Flow matrix below, both the HSV and magnitude matrices. But I don't know how to calculate a **average** total movement magnitude. How can I calculate it from those matrices?

```
def optical_flow(one, two):
    one_g = cv2.cvtColor(one, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    two_g = cv2.cvtColor(two, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    hsv = np.zeros((120, 320, 3))
    # set saturation
    hsv[:,:,1] = cv2.cvtColor(two, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)[:,:,1]
    # obtain dense optical flow paramters
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(one_g, two_g, flow=None,
                                        pyr_scale=0.5, levels=1, winsize=15,
                                        iterations=2,
                                        poly_n=5, poly_sigma=1.1, flags=0)
    # convert from cartesian to polar
    mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
    # hue corresponds to direction
    hsv[:,:,0] = ang * (180/ np.pi / 2)
    # value corresponds to magnitude
    hsv[:,:,2] = cv2.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    # convert HSV to int32's
    hsv = np.asarray(hsv, dtype= np.float32)
    rgb_flow = cv2.cvtColor(hsv,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
    return rgb_flow
```

The `rgb_flow` is a 3D array looks like this:

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]


 ...


 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

And the `mag` matrix is 2D array like this:

```
[[3.2825139e-03 3.9561605e-03 4.8938910e-03 ... 3.7310597e-02
  3.2986153e-02 2.5520157e-02]
 [4.9569397e-03 6.3276174e-03 7.7017904e-03 ... 3.9564677e-02
  3.2582227e-02 2.6329078e-02]
 ...

 [6.9548332e-06 8.3683852e-05 6.0906638e-03 ... 8.3484064e-04
  6.4721738e-04 2.9505073e-04]]
```

Comment: You have to think a little harder about what you're asking.  What do you want this single number to represent?  The average optical flow?  The maximum optical flow?  Or do you want to guess how much the camera moved?

Comment: The average over all scene frames probably. I thought that can be a good representation of a fast-moving scene.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
np.mean(mag)
```

This will give you the average magnitude.  Even though the numpy array mag is 2d, np.mean reduces this to a single number by default. Also, you may be better served by median since mean is sensitive to outliers.

```
np.median(mag)
```

Comment: While this code may/may no solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations.